# Autorelease vs. release

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

When I need an array for temporary use, what's the difference between these:

1:

```
NSMutableArray *stuff = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// use the array
[stuff release];
```

2:

```
NSMutableArray *stuff = [NSMutableArray array];
// use the array
```

3:

```
NSMutableArray *stuff = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
// use the array
```

I prefer number 2, since it's shorter. Are there any good reasons to use number 1 or 3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Number 2 is likely the best choice in most cases.

Number 1 has the chance of losing the release at some point down the line, for whatever reason, but it does release the array *immediately*, which in memory-starved environments can be useful.

Number 3 is basically a verbose equivalent of number 2, but it does come in handy if you want to use an initWith* that doesn't have a corresponding arrayWith*.

*Note:* If you *are* memory-starved, such as in an expensive loop where you need a fresh array for each iteration; *don't* release and allocate new arrays; just use `-removeAllObjects` and recycle the array.

Comment: Thanks! Good point about the immediate release of memory in number 1.

Comment: On the iPhone, you'll find most people use number 1 because the memory gets given back to the runtime sooner.  In fact, Apple recommend avoiding autorelease as much as possible (on the iPhone).

Comment: Good answer, save for the last bit.  I'd wager that the difference between creating a new array on each pass and removing all objects is immeasurable and, quite likely, removing all objects will be trivially slower.  In any case, don't optimize until you have a quantified performance problem.

Comment: @bburn: How could removing all objects be slower than releasing the array; as the former is a part of the process for the latter?