# Use autorelease when setting a retain property using dot syntax?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, memory-management, autorelease

I see in some sample code that `autorelease` is used. I am not familiar with the instances when this is required. For example, if I create an annotation object

Header file

```
@interface someViewController: UIViewController 
{
    Annotation *annotation;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Annotation *annotation;

@end
```

Implementation file

```
@implementation someViewController
@synthesize annotation
@end
```

Question: Is it the correct approach if I initialize my annotation object in the implementation file like this?

```
self.annotation = [[Annotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
```

Do I need to set autorelease for this? Or can I just do it the normal way and add the release in the dealloc method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autorelease vs. release](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077159/autorelease-vs-release) and there are many, many other questions that will answer this if you take the time to read them: [Search: iPhone retain property autorelease](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+retain+property+autorelease) This: [Release/autorelease confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121343/release-autorelease-confusion-in-cocoa-for-iphone) is probably one of the best.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this is correct:

`self.annotation = [[[Annotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location] autorelease];`

because annotation property is declared as a retain property, so assigning to it will increment its retain count.

you will also need, all the same, to release self.annotation in `-dealloc`.

in short:

1. init will set retain count to 1;
2. assigning to self.annotation, will set it to 2;
3. autorelease will set it back to 1 when the main loop is executed again;
4. release in dealloc will set the retain count to 0, so that the object will be deallocated);

the best way to think of `autorelease` is the following, in my opinion: `autorelease` will "schedule" an "automatic" `release` for your object at some (near) point in future (typically when the control flow goes back to the main loop, but details are hidden in the hands of Apple).

`autorelease` is mostly useful in conjunction with `init`, specifically in the following cases:

1. when you `init` a local variable, so that you don't have to `release` it explicitly before it goes out of scope (the main loop will do that for you);
2. when you return a pointer to an object you have just created without keeping ownership of it (typical case of the `create/make*` kind of selectors, the receiver is required to `retain` it to get ownership);
3. with properties that `retain`, when you assign to them an object that they should own uniquely;
4. with data structures that increment the retain count (`NSMutableArray`, `NSMutableDictionary`, etc): you should generally `autorelease` a newly `init`ed object when you add it to such data structure.

apart from case 2, it is evident that the use of `autorelease` is meant to improve readability of the code and reduce the potential for errors (meaning that in all of the other cases, you could simply `release` explicitly your object after the assignment or at the end of the scope).

when using properties, you have always to check whether they are of the `retain` or `assign`/`copy` case; in the first case, assigning a newly `init`ed object to a property generally requires `autorelease`.

Anyway, I would suggest at least skimming one of the many tutorial on [memory management for iOS](http://www.google.es/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=objective-c%20memory%20management&aq=f&aqi=g4g-b2&aql=f&oq=).

Comment: One quick gotcha, if you write `annotation = [[Annotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];` without the `self` the retain count will not increase.

Answer (score 2):

Autorelease is telling the object to release itself before leaving the scope.

Sometimes when you code, you'll encounter something like this

```
- (void)doSomething
{
    if(true)
    {
        NSString *foo = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"foo"];

        //Some execution here

        [foo release];
    }
}

- (void)doSomething
{
    if(true)
    {
        //By doing this is telling to to release foo object before getting out of the scope
        //which is similar with above practice
        NSString *foo = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"foo"] autorelease];

        //Or you can do it this way
        NSString *foo = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"foo"];
        [foo autorelease];

        //Some execution carry on, it'll release foo before entering next scope

    }
```

//This is out of the scope
    }

Of course, releasing an object doesn't mean deallocating the object.
Sometimes you retain the object so you can still use it outside of its scope.

Judging from your question, if your the object is located within your header file/interface.
You should release it in dealloc method. CMIIW.

Comment: just to clarify, my understanding is that even if the object is in the header file, we might still need to execute autorelease if for example self.annotation = [[Annotation alloc]init... happens. Is that correct?

Comment: @Zhen usually you'll initialize your interface object (even making it nil). Thus releasing in dealloc is a must. But if by some chance you init your object again (which will cause memory leak because you lost your previous memory address), yes, you can set autorelease. Remember when we alloc and init, we're talking about memory address.  This is what I know, you can read/ask experienced programmer if you wish to learn more.