# BOOL - potential leak of an object

Tags: objective-c

i am getting potential leak of an object allocated message. how can i dealloc it?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

  extern BOOL _mainWebViewLoaded;  // **-> Potential leak of an object allocated

    Nimble *nimble = [[Nimble alloc] initWithRootPage:@"main.html" window:self.window serial:@""];
    [nimble release]; 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    while (!_mainWebViewLoaded) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
    }
    return YES ;



}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's self.window that is leaked, not the BOOL. Autorelease your self.window:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
```

The reasoning is explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055325/33112).

Comment: Thank you so much.. i am new obj-c and thank you for the link that helped me a lot to understand...

Comment: It was my pleasure. We're all new to something!